# How to compare 2 URL adres with PHPUnit?

Tags: php, url, phpunit

I am working on a task that is expose a xml file with given url. I want to test my code and I do this with PHPUnit. I used composer to install PHPUnit.

The example test that I want to run is this :

```
<?php
    use PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase;

    class IndexTest extends TestCase{

    public function testGetXmlWithUrl(){
    require 'index.php';

    $XmlClass = new XmlReaderClass("localhost", "8000", "status.xml", "");
    $url= $XmlClass->$url;
    $myUrl = "http://localhost:8000/status.xml?password=";
    
    $this->assertEquals($myUrl, $url);

}}  ?>
```

TestCase class cannot be added. I mean even PhpUnit name is not colored in blue in the code. So I guess I could not include it in my project actually. Error is like:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase' not found in /Users/demetsen/Desktop/tests/IndexTest.php:4

My second problem is when I try to run testGetXmlWithUrl() method the result is :

> Failed asserting that SimpleXMLElement Object (...) matches expected '\n ....

Why am I getting this result and how can I solve it?

Comment: Hello Demet, can you show us how are you running the tests?

Comment: Hi, I run like this: phpunit tests/IndexTest.php

Comment: Where you are calling phpunit from, is there a `phpunit.xml` file located in that directory? If so, can you share it here?

Comment: there is no such  phpunit.xml file in my project. Should I add it. If so, how can I do it? Thanks.

Comment: You dont need phpunit.xml. Do you run this command from the directory where tests directory is, NOT from tests directory? run `cat tests/IndexTest.php` instead of `phpunit tests/IndexTest.php` and you should see contents of this test file. If you dont the path is wrong. There are no more steps for this to work: https://phpunit.de/getting-started-with-phpunit.html

Comment: Please share more details. Also, explain how this is related to Composer

Answer (score 1):

A default `phpunit.xml` (or better, use `phpunit.xml.dist`, so you can copy/edit it locally if needed), can be created with `phpunit --generate-configuration` will include a line for `bootstrap`:

```
<phpunit
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="https://schema.phpunit.de/6.3/phpunit.xsd"
     bootstrap="path/to/bootstrap.php"
     <!-- more lines -->
</phpunit>
```

Here, the `bootstrap="...."` line can, at its simplest, point to the composer autoloader. PHPunit can also create a suitable file for you.

```
$ php ./phpunit-9.2.phar --generate-configuration  # or vendor/bin/phpunit, via composer
PHPUnit 9.2.6 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.

Generating phpunit.xml in /home/username/code/test

Bootstrap script (relative to path shown above; default: vendor/autoload.php):
Tests directory (relative to path shown above; default: tests):
Source directory (relative to path shown above; default: src):

Generated phpunit.xml in /home/username/code/test

# optional, but useful:
# mv phpunit.xml phpunit.xml.dist  # .dist will be read if .xml does not exist
```

The output file:

```
$ cat phpunit.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<phpunit xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="https://schema.phpunit.de/9.2/phpunit.xsd"
         bootstrap="vendor/autoload.php"
         executionOrder="depends,defects"
         forceCoversAnnotation="true"
         beStrictAboutCoversAnnotation="true"
         beStrictAboutOutputDuringTests="true"
         beStrictAboutTodoAnnotatedTests="true"
         verbose="true">
    <testsuites>
        <testsuite name="default">
            <directory suffix="Test.php">tests</directory>
        </testsuite>
    </testsuites>

    <filter>
        <whitelist processUncoveredFilesFromWhitelist="true">
            <directory suffix=".php">src</directory>
        </whitelist>
    </filter>
</phpunit>
```

If you had something you needed to add to the bootstrap process, create a file with your needs, and you'd probably also add something like `require __DIR__.'/vendor/autoload.php';` to setup the autoloading.

Comment: The require statement in the end of the answer is lacking a directory separator. It should be: `require __DIR__.'/vendor/autoload.php';`